# HTML5 Parallax Scrolling utility using canvas

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas, parallax

I have created a utility to create scrolling parallax backgrounds.

```
// Backgrounds as array of objects. canvas id, speed, image url
var bgs = [{
  id: 'sky',
  speed: 1,
  src: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9f/Sky_back_layer.png'
}, {
  id: 'middle',
  speed: 3,
  src: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8b/Vegetation_%28middle_layer%29.png'
}, {
  id: 'front',
  speed: 5,
  src: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/be/Ground_%28front_layer%29.png'
}];

// Create render background through Scenery
var Scenery = {
  bgs: [],
  // Initialize individual canvases and set images
  init: function(bgs) {
    var i = bgs.length - 1,j = 0;
    for (; i >= 0; i--,j++) {
      this.bgs[j] = {};
      this.bgs[j].cvs = document.getElementById(bgs[i].id);
      this.bgs[j].ctx = this.bgs[j].cvs.getContext('2d');
      this.bgs[j].img = document.createElement('img');
      this.bgs[j].img.src = bgs[i].src;
      this.bgs[j].left = 0;
      this.bgs[j].speed=bgs[i].speed;
    }
  },
  // According to scroll speed, render images in corresponding canvas
  // To have a seamless effect, render image twice
  scene: function() {
    var i = this.bgs.length - 1,
      left, w, h, bgNow, bgCtx;
    for (; i >= 0; i--) {
      bgNow = this.bgs[i];
      left = bgNow.left;
      w = bgNow.cvs.width;
      h = bgNow.cvs.height;
      bgCtx = bgNow.ctx;

      bgCtx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
      bgCtx.drawImage(this.bgs[i].img, -left, 0, w, h);
      bgCtx.drawImage(this.bgs[i].img, w - left, 0, w, h);
      this.bgs[i].left = (left + this.bgs[i].speed) % w;
    }

  }
};

// This handles looping . A wrapper around window.requestAnimationFrame
// Considers frame rate.
var Loop = {
  run: function(scene, fps) {
    this.scene = scene;
    this.frameInterval = 1000 / fps;
    this.lastTime = new Date().getTime();

    this.loop();
  },
  loop: function() {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var elapsed = now - this.lastTime;
    if (elapsed >= this.frameInterval) {

      this.scene();
      this.lastTime = now;
    }
    window.requestAnimationFrame(this.loop.bind(this));
  }
};

// Initialize scenery
Scenery.init(bgs);
// Run it
Loop.run(Scenery.scene.bind(Scenery), 60);
```

HTML

```
<div>
  <canvas id='sky'></canvas>
  <canvas id='middle'></canvas>
  <canvas id='front'></canvas>
</div>
```

Styles

```
div {
  position: relative;
}

canvas {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

My question is, is there a better approach to pass Scenery.scene function into Loop.run()?